# Log file is not being created by class library after installing the dll

Tags: c#

I have created a class library with some functionality and maintaining a log file to track the steps executed. If i run this class library in debug mode it is successfully creating log file.

But, I have created the cab file after creating the tlb file of that class library and installed into the system. Now i am using that library, all the functions are working properly, only logs files are not written.

I've used the code to create log file is below-

```
 public static void LogTrace(string LogMessage)
    {
        try
        {

            string LogError = string.Empty;
            String DirPath = string.Empty;

            DirPath= Convert.ToString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DirPath"]);
            LogError = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LogError"]);

            //if logging is not required
            if (LogError.ToLower() == "true")
            {
                if (DirPath == null || DirPath == string.Empty)
                    DirPath = @"C:\LogAndError";

                if (LogError == null || LogError == string.Empty)
                    LogError = "True";

                //creation of date wise file name

                string LogFileName = DirPath + "\\Log_ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".txt";
                createLogAndErrorFile(DirPath);

                    StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
                    streamWriter = new StreamWriter(LogFileName, true);
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("Time :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  ");
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(LogMessage);
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //We are not throwing any exception because all the exeption is logged using this method
            //and throwing the exception could lead to recursive call of function.
        }
    }
    public static void createLogAndErrorFile(string DirPath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(DirPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(DirPath);
    }
}
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: I'm having no issues with it, where does your DirPath point ? Do you have write rights in that directory and does if (LogError.ToLower() == "true") return true ?

Comment: @CooLMinE I have Defined "D:\LogsAndErrors" in the DirPath.. Although it is writting log when running in build mode.  but if i use the dll in another project only then it is not writing..

Comment: Make sure you have `LogError` defined in the client config or change the first `if (LogError == "true"). I would also suggest that instead of swallowing the error you either let it throw and unhandled exception or fallback to the event log.

Comment: There's no evidence that you tried to debug this problem.  Start there first.

Comment: @Gary.S Definily LogError == "true" in configuration file.. I alreay told it is working. but not working when i am using the dll in another project

Comment: When you use the dll in another project, that projects app.config MUST contain the LogError setting or you need to make sure its not null before testing it.

Comment: Also, as mentioned previously, remove the empty catch or do something in the catch so that you can see the specific error being thrown, my best guess is a Null Ref exception but the only way to be sure is to report/record the error.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have permission to acces to your file

Place your code in try catch block and capture exception
I suggest you to use using block

```
try
{

           var path = Path.Combine(DirPath, string.Concat("\\Log_",DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy"), ".txt"));

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Time :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  ");
                streamWriter.WriteLine(LogMessage);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            }


}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   Console.Write(ex.Message);
   throw ex;
}
```

Comment: I already told that it is properly. But when using the dll in other application, then it is not writing log.

Comment: No.. If any exception was occurring, I am not able to know in the dll.